# FormSet - why we should use it?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am reading about FormSets in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) and I am having a problem understanding the sense of this feature. Maybe example with articles is unfortunate, but how often do we want to show several identical forms on the same page? Why should I do it? Do you know better examples - what are advantages of formsets and when use their?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this whenever you have a series of child records associated with a parent. A family and its members; a book and its chapters; a class and its students; a shopping basket and its contents... the list goes on.
All of these involve one master form and a whole set of identical child forms, and you can use the inline version of formsets to do this - which is how the Django admin's inline feature works.

Answer (score 0):

Formsets are used when you need to create multiple instances of a model. For example, maybe you're having a party, and you want to add multiple guests to your party. You could use a formset for your "Guest" model to add as many as you'd like at one time.

Formsets are a very powerful feature of Django, in my opinion.